Can the landlord ban my boyfriend from coming over if he doesn't want this background check and credit
A. My boyfriend doesn't live with me but comes over everyday because I use his truck for work. Now the landlord says he can't be on the property if he doesn't fill out an application n be put on my lease or if caught on property I can get evicted.Can they do that? I live in Arizona

doesn't live with me but comes over everyday - what's the distinction really?

@littleadv where he sleeps and possibly whether he maintains a residence elsewhere.  For the landlord's purposes, the residence elsewhere is less likely to be relevant than it might be for someone else.  Stacia Jordan: is he sleeping at your place or just visiting during the day?

Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/102900/can-a-rental-agreement-state-that-no-guests-or-parties-are-allowed

While this is off topic as asking for legal advice, the statement that he comes over everyday needs a lot more details such as how long he stays each day and how many days a week it is.

What does the truck have to do with it? Does he bring the truck to you, then stay in your apartment all day until you come home? That's getting pretty close to living there.

@phoog or he works night shifts and really comes home to sleep. As a landlord, I expect everyone constantly present in my property to be known and sign a lease, I don't care how they divide their time.

@littleadv in some jurisdictions (or at least one, namely New York City) a landlord cannot require everyone living in an apartment to be named on the lease; more specifically, a landlord who has leased an apartment to a single adult cannot prevent the tenant from taking an adult roommate.  Landlords also do not have unlimited capacity to restrict tenants' visitors, and different jurisdictions will have different rules about that.  Suppose your tenant had a full-time or even live-in nanny: would you require the nanny to be on the lease?

@phoog Fortunately I don't have properties in NYC. In the States and cities where I do it is absolutely permissible to demand that and I would most certainly do, I'd lose my liability coverage otherwise.

Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/102900/can-a-rental-agreement-state-that-no-guests-or-parties-are-allowed
